# Does a program clear all variables each time it is run?

Tags: python, runtime

I'm pretty new to programming and having difficulty understanding exactly what happens at program runtime. My question relates to this bit of code in Python:

```
list1 = []
input_from_user = input("Enter word: ")
list1.append(input_from_user)
for i in list1:
    print(i)
```

Why is it that every time I run the program, the list1 variable seems to refresh itself? In other words, if I run the program once and input 'Hello' when prompted, then run the program a second time and input 'World', the program only outputs 'World' after the second run. Why doesn't the list1 variable grow in size by 1 word each time I run the program, instead of 'forgetting', so to speak, what happened the last time I ran the program? Is there a way to define or store variables in such a way that they maintain the value they had at the conclusion of the previous runtime?

Comment: It "forgets" because you didn't tell it to "remember" in that particular way. You should do a bit of research into the various kinds of memory in a computer.

Comment: If you want persistent data, you would need to store the data on disk

Comment: [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the tutorial is a decent place to start.

Comment: What you're asking for isn't _ridiculous_ or anything, it's just not the way most programming languages are designed. There are a few Lisp and Smalltalk environments that make everything persistent by default (and some experimental or toy languages you only learn about in programming language theory classes). But normally, people follow the Unix model, where quitting is expected to give you a "clean slate", and any persistence you want has to be explicitly added on top of it.

Comment: In addition to not remembering the list, you also *explicitly set it to the empty list* at the start of your program. So even if Python magically remembered the old value, you'd be explicitly telling it to reset it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! That helps to clear up some of my questions. Is there a specific file format that is recommended for storing the kind of data that the program can read? And is pickling the way to go here, or is there a different way to store data to disk?

Comment: Did you try Googling any of that? It's a well-documented, basic task.

Answer (score 1):

"Does a program clear all the variables each time it is run?"

Yes.

You see, each time you run the program, it sets the variables again.

```
A = 0

A = A + 1
```

Variable A starts with the value 0, then increments by one. If you run the program again, A will be set to 0, then increment by one.

The program doesn't necessarily *clear* the variables, so to speak, but simply doesn't actually store them anywhere. When you start the program a new variable is created each time, and when the program ends the variable disappears.

If you want to store the values of the variable, I suggest looking into the Pickle Module.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: No problem, I know how it feels when you're just beginning to program. Figured I'd help you out :)